# Merging 2 post-unstacked DataFrames back to a single DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Having 2 similar unstack'ed df's but the merge or joining difficulty is raising doubts on approach..

1st df post-unstack with 2 columns sect_classif & isInPartition:

```
instru_id date          sect_classif  isInPartition
123       31.03.2020    35            1.0
456       31.03.2020    45            1.0
789       31.03.2020    50            1.0
1111      31.03.2020    50            1.0
```

2nd df post-unstack with 1 column sect_classif_instru_weights:

```
sect_classif   date         sect_classif_instru_weights
35             31.03.2020   0.0054
45             31.03.2020   0.0060
50             31.03.2020   0.0027
```

Trying to get to similar 1st df but with isInPartition replaced using data from the 2nd df based on sect_classif:

```
instru_id date          sect_classif  sect_classif_instru_weights
123       31.03.2020    35            0.0054
456       31.03.2020    45            0.0060
789       31.03.2020    50            0.0027
1111      31.03.2020    50            0.0027
```

Is above doable or have I gone down an un-necessary unstack rabbit hole.. ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions..

Comment: You want to inner join using both columns: `df1.join(df2, on=['istru_id', 'date'], how='inner')`

Comment: Thanks. Def leap forward. Applied join with on=['sect_classif','date']

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`pandas.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).  Create a Series from `df2` with `sect_classif_instru_weights` as values and `sect_classif` as the index.  Use this to fill `df1`:

```
mapper = pd.Series(df2['sect_classif_instru_weights'].values, index=df2['sect_classif'])
df1['isInPartition'] = df1['sect_classif'].map(mapper)
```

Result:

```
   instru_id        date  sect_classif  isInPartition
0        123  31.03.2020            35         0.0054
1        456  31.03.2020            45         0.0060
2        789  31.03.2020            50         0.0027
3       1111  31.03.2020            50         0.0027
```

`mapper` is acting like a `dict` here:

```
sect_classif
35    0.0054
45    0.0060
50    0.0027
dtype: float64
```

Comment: As a shortcut you could also use `mapper = df2.set_index('sect_classif')['sect_classif_instru_weights']` :)